# Ubuntu and AMD graphics cards

Tags: ati, graphics, 14.10, gpu-driver

Have had trouble with the last few distros and my AMD graphics card giving me unusable screen.  Does AMD play nice with Ubuntu now?

Comment: Mine works perfectly but others have reported problems. Try searching this site for the model of your graphics card.

Comment: Will do, thank you!  Hadn't actually thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

The answer *still* isn't black and white. There are two different drivers (and soon a third that aims to superset both). There is still no clear winner between the two. Here's a snippet [from the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI):

> The open source driver is currently not on par with the proprietary driver in terms of 3D performance on newer cards or reliable TV-out support. It does, however, offer better dual-head support, excellent 2D acceleration, and provide sufficient 3D acceleration for OpenGL-accelerated window managers, such as Compiz or KWin.

Which works best for you will likely still depend on your hardware and the applications you want to run. Expect it to be an iterative and occasionally frustrating process.

If you're asking about buying suggestions, I'd personally avoid them until they can deliver a driver that works. That is their aim but progress to date has been slow. If you want high performance and parity between Windows and Linux, you buy Nvidia. If you want a solid open driver stack (for KMS, Wayland, etc) you get something with an Intel IGP.